# Why this ngx-leaflet params are not working properly?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet, ngx-leaflet-draw

I´m trying to make everything as possible in my `leaflet` project in `Angular` with `ngx-angular` but can´t find the way to make them work properly.

This is my params code:

```
zoomControl = {position: 'bottomright'};

readonly drawOptions = {
position: 'topright',
draw: {
  circle: false,
  circlemarker: false
},
edit: {
  featureGroup: this.drawItems,
  remove: false
  }
};
```

As you can see on this snapshot, this doesn´t works, `position` params are ignored and `circle and circlemarker` properties are ignored too.

[image]

Of course, they are included into the `div` map tag that has the `ngx-leaflet` properties calls, I wish to know if it´s possible to make them work without using pure JS on the way.

Comment: stackblitz please

Comment: @alessandro don´t know who to use stackblitz and if it´s possible to install there npm libraries, sorry

Comment: I suggest to play here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter 
It will help you a lot

All the best

Comment: Okey, I will try @alessandro

Comment: Sorry @alessandro but can´t implement it there, it makes me nervous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ngx-leaflet-draw` library to be able to achieve what you are trying to.

Here include `leafletDrawOptions` to equal a variable `drawOptions` defined on your component:

```
<div
  leaflet
  style="height: 400px;"
  leafletDraw
  [leafletOptions]="options"
  [leafletDrawOptions]="drawOptions"
  (leafletDrawCreated)="onDrawCreated($event)"
>
  <div [leafletLayer]="drawnItems"></div>
</div>
```

In your component you are able to define which options will be visible like you are trying to in your example above:

```
{
    position: "topleft",
    draw: {
      ...,
      polyline: false,
      circle: false,
      circlemarker: false,
      rectangle: {
        shapeOptions: {
          color: "#85bb65"
        }
      }
    },
    edit: {
      featureGroup: this.drawnItems,
      remove: false
    }
  };
```

Here is the [guide](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw) on how to install `ngx-leaflet-draw` and here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ngx-leaflet-draw-options-j6jqx?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:616-1312) to see it live. Do not worry regarding the drawing icons not being visible. In your app it should be fine. It has to do with codesandbox.

Comment: thanks for the answer mate, I solved it yesterdey but was as you said